# Where is the script that creates home folders in linux?

Tags: scripting, fedora, user-management

I want to added public_html and private_html folders for users of my web server (Fedora 8 or 10 or something).  Where is the script that will create those folders for them when they log on?  Is there one script for first logon and a different script for subsequent logons?  What is the normal way this is accomplished?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fedora will copy the contents of /etc/skel into your newly created home directories upon account creation. You can just toss empty public_html and private_html directories there.

Comment: It's not just Fedora - that's a standard location for Linux/Unix distributions in general.

Answer (score 4):

In *debian* you can provide a script that is run after adduser is called. Perhaps fedora has something analog. You can use this script, if you have further things to do...

Here a snippet from *man adduser*

```
If the file /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local exists, it will be executed  
after the user account has been set up in order to do any local setup.  
The  arguments passed to adduser.local are:
username uid gid home-directory
The environment variable VERBOSE is set according to the following rule:

0 if --quiet is specified

1 if neither --quiet nor --debug is specified

2 if --debug is specified

(The same applies to the variable DEBUG, but DEBUG is deprecated 
and will be removed in a later version of adduser.)
```